# Thymeleaf-Not able to append '/' in html

Tags: thymeleaf

```
<span th:each="entry: ${productOptionDisplayValues}">
<span th:if="${entry?.key != 'OfferStatus'}">
<span th:if="${entry?.key=='color_'}" th:text="${entry.value}+ ' / '"/>
<span th:unless="${entry?.key=='color_'}" th:text="${entry.value}"/>
</span>
</span>
```

I have the following span tag in my html where i am iterating on a map and printing the key value.
At the end of first if block , after printing the value i want to appand a '/' for which i am appending + ' / ' at the end of first if block.
But it's appearing as '아이보리 T38' where instead of / , T is getting appended after the color variance.
It should come as '아이보리 / 38'

Answer (score 0):

If you want Thymeleaf to respect your XHTML or HTML5 tags and not escape them,
You will have to use a different attribute: `th:utext` (for "unescaped text").